# VLOOKUP average a range of cells

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a standard VLOOKUP formula

```
=VLOOKUP($G28,'Analysis 1'!$A$2:$CR$32,$M28+$M28,TRUE)
```

How would I amend this so that rather than just return the answer i would want it to average the result of 3 cells, the cell above the VLOOKUP, the cell below the VLOOKUP and the cell of the VLOOKUP?

I would also be good if I can specify the number of cells either side of the vlookup i want to average, so in the case above it would be 1.

Comment: Use **Match()** rather than **VLOOKUP()**.  **Match()** gets you the row number.  Once you have the row number, you can retrieve/manipulate any data with respect to that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use MATCH.

I think the easiest way to do this is using the OFFSET function:-

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)-D2,0,D2*2+1))
```

Where the lookup value is in E2 and the number of cells to include either side is in D2. If D2 contains zero, you just get the value corresponding to the key (25). The Lookup and Return columns don't need to be together.

The example includes the cells in column B containing 9,16,25,36 and 49 and gives the answer 27.

I should probably add error handling for the cases where the cells are too near to the end or beginning of the range to give the right answer when time allows.

[image]

Here is the formula with error handling:-

```
=IFERROR(
  IF(OR((MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)-D2)<1,(MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)+D2)>ROWS(B2:B11)),
      "Out of range",
       AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)-D2,0,D2*2+1))),
  "Not found")
```

Here is the formula modified to 'taper off' at the ends of the range so the number of cells either side is a maximum of n, where n is the number of cells between the matching cell and the end of the range:-

```
=IFERROR(
   AVERAGE(OFFSET(B$1,
     MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-MIN(MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-1,ROWS(A$2:A$11)-MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0),D$2),0,
     MIN(MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-1,ROWS(A$2:A$11)-MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0),D$2)*2+1)),
  "Not found")
```

[image]

---

**Update**

INDEX may be preferred to OFFSET because it is not volatile.

Here are the two formulae using INDEX:-

```
=IFERROR(
      IF(OR((MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)-D2)<1,(MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)+D2)>ROWS(B2:B11)),
          "Out of range",
           AVERAGE(INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)-D2):INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(E2,A2:A11,0)+D2) )),
"Not found")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(
     AVERAGE(
         INDEX(B$2:B$11,MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-MIN(MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-1,ROWS(A$2:A$11)-MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0),D$2)):
         INDEX(B$2:B$11,MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)+MIN(MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0)-1,ROWS(A$2:A$11)-MATCH(E2,A$2:A$11,0),D$2))),
   "Not found")
```

Comment: I will give this a go today and let you know how i get on, many thanks

Comment: i see you have covered the error handling aspect should the lookup be the last row of the table, is it possible to amend it so that should the lookup be the last row of the table, then it would average the last 3 rows, rather than say not found?

Comment: Good question! Would the same thing apply to the first row of the table? What if it was the last but one and you wanted two cells either side?

Comment: How about 'tapering it off' so that if the matching cell is n cells from the end, you include a maximum of n cells either side. So if it's at the end (n=0), just take the value of the last cell.

Comment: hello Tom, you are absolutely right, this would apply to the first cell in the column also. This works perfectly thank you for this,

Comment: @ Tom Sharpe, how would this work where TRUE was applied in the usual VLOOKUP so that the VLOOKUP was approximate match?

Comment: If you take out the third parameter of the MATCH statements so the basic formula is =AVERAGE(OFFSET(B1,MATCH(E2,A2:A11)-D2,0,D2*2+1)) it will behave like VLOOKUP( ...TRUE). So for my last two values in the last screenshot it would return 100 for 11 and 1 for 1.5 The values in the Lookup range have to be in ascending order.

Comment: Brilliant you're a star!